# How to set node env variables (runtime) after build the React project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, environment-variables, runtime

I'm setting up ReactJS Project to change environment variables at Run-time.

I have 2 ENV variables:

1) NODE_ENV = Production, Development

2) FLAVOUR = Alpha, Beta

I want to load different configurations, theme and images based on `FLAVOUR` variable. Which is already done and working.

Build commands:

1) cross-env NODE_ENV=production --env.FLAVOUR=Alpha webpack

2) cross-env NODE_ENV=production --env.FLAVOUR=Beta webpack

--

But above commands are changing env variables at Build-Time. But I want to change `FLAVOUR` variable only for Production env at Run-Time after the build.

Ex. ./build cross-env --env.FLAVOUR=Alpha node server

Ex. ./build cross-env --env.FLAVOUR=Beta node server

./build is build directory, created by npm run build command.

--

Which means when I change the `FLAVOUR` variable to `Beta` and restart the web app
My expectation is that it will be the `Beta` app and Theme.
This helps us with scaling these webapps. They can be re-purposed on a dime.

Webpack Production:

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'process.env.FLAVOUR': JSON.stringify(process.env.FLAVOUR),
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this answers your question, but I have set up my project using webpack as the following

```
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      ENV: process.env.ENV || 'development',
      API_BASE: process.env.API_BASE,
    }),
```

I have `API_BASE` defined in an `.env` file which webpack picks up when I run `yarn start` for development

Once I am done developing, I build a production docker image and I can overwrite the `API_BASE` in the environment file while running the image as

```
docker build -t yourProjectName .
docker run -e API_BASE='http:\/\/yourIPAddress:port/' -p 9000:80 yourProjectName
```

This is possible because in my Dockerfile I run bash script whenever the image runs

```
RUN chmod +x setup.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/setup.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and the setup.sh file

```
/bin/sed -i "s||${API_BASE}|g" /usr/share/nginx/html/app.*.js
exec "$@"
```

The script looks for the string `http://localhost:5000/` and replaces it with whatever you pass during runtime

Hope this helps!

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem today and have solved it by making process.env available through webpack externals.

```js
const config = {
  externals: [{ processEnv: 'process.env' }, nodeExternals({})],
}
```

The line above tells webpack that there is a dependency called processEnv and should be resolved by referencing `process.env`. It outputs a small commonjs module.

```js
// WEBPACK'S BUILD
/***/ "processEnv":
/*!******************************!*\
  !*** external "process.env" ***!
  \******************************/
/***/ ((module) => {

"use strict";
module.exports = process.env;

/***/ }),
```

In your code, you can require this shim by doing.

```js
const processEnv = require('processEnv')
```

I have documented the process in more detail here https://blog.freemiumpn.com/docs/developer/how-to/web/runtime-configs-with-webpack-and-docker-v2

Comment: [webpack-cli] ReferenceError: nodeExternals is not defined
Getting the above error. Could you provide more details on how to do this?